# phpMyAdmin - how to save a SPATIAL Point

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to store a Spatial Point in a dataBase in phpMyAdmin and I don't know why is always shown like [GEOMETRY-25B]. Below is the command I use.

```
INSERT INTO `locations`(`Location`) VALUES (GeomFromText( 'POINT(40 -100)'))
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `locations`(`Location`) VALUES (Point(40,-100))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Options, then select "Full text" and "Well Known Text".

Comment: Well Marc, I have Full Texts in Options but there is nowhere WellKnownText. If I click Full Texts nothing changes.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version 4.0.7 and now the "Well Known Text" Option is shown. And the points are visible! Thanks a lot Marc!

Answer (score 1):

I found something. The points are stored ok and if you try to execute the query below it returns the points as POINT(4 5) for example. But how can I make them visible to the table?

```
 SELECT AsText(`Location`) FROM `products`
```

Update:
As @Marc mentioned above, after the upgrade of phpMyAdmin to the latest version 4.0.7 there is an Option "Well Known Text" which makes points visible to the table.

Comment: Watch this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIGFRI5hbco starting at 8:00, it's me explaining all this.